# Understanding Swift's Closure Type Requirements

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to get into the habit of doing things the Swifty way instead of translating Obj-C.

I'm doing a project with Parse, and after fetching a bunch of Parse objects, I want to first sort them, then extract a particular property from them. This is what I'm trying right now:

```
if let notifications = fetchedObjects as? [PFObject] {
    // This line tells me "Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'
    let sortedMessages: [String] = notifications.sorted { $0.createdAt.compare($1.createdAt) == .OrderedAscending }
}
```

`PFObject` has a `createdAt` property declared like this: `var createdAt: NSDate? { get }`.

What am I missing here that messes with Swift's type checking?

Here's what I want to after figuring out the above error:

```
if let notifications = fetchedObjects as? [PFObject] {
    let sortedMessages: [String] = notifications.sorted({ $0.createdAt.compare($1.createdAt) == .OrderedAscending }).map { $0["message"] }
}
```

This looks to me like all types should be clear and matching.

**UPDATE**

I came back to this today and got it working. I didn't write it in my original post, but yesterday I did try to force unwrap the `createdAt` optional too:

```
if let notifications = fetchedObjects as? [PFObject] {
    // This line tells me "Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'
    let sortedMessages: [String] = notifications.sorted { $0.createdAt!.compare($1.createdAt!) == .OrderedAscending }
}
```

That was giving me the exact same error. One thing I've learned playing with Swift so far is that when it's giving cryptic type mismatch errors, it's best to explicitly add type declarations to every variable - this often leads to more specific error messages. So, today, I wrote the above code like this:

```
    if let notifications = objects as? [PFObject] {
        let sortedMessages: [String] = notifications.sorted { (lhs: PFObject, rhs: PFObject) -> Bool in
            return rhs.createdAt!.compare(lhs.createdAt!) == .OrderedAscending
            }.map { $0["message"] as! String }
    }
```

This seems to compile without a problem. But if I rely on type inference:

```
    if let notifications = objects as? [PFObject] {
        let sortedMessages: [String] = notifications.sorted { lhs, rhs in
            return rhs.createdAt!.compare(lhs.createdAt!) == .OrderedAscending
            }.map { $0["message"] as! String }
    }
```

I get an error on `map`: `Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'`.

It looks to me like this:

```
if let notifications = objects as? [PFObject] {
    let sortedMessages: [String] = notifications.sorted { $0.createdAt!.compare($1.createdAt!) == .OrderedAscending }
       .map { $0["message"] as! String }
}
```

should be valid, but Swift's type inference isn't up to snuff yet... (?). I'm not comfortable letting myself off the hook and blame the language, but it looks reasonable in this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: What type does `$0["message"]` return? `AnyObject!`?

Comment: Correct. `AnyObject!`.

Answer (score 1):

The types don't quite match up. `createdAt` is an `Optional`, and the `compare` method takes in a non-optional. Also, without knowing exactly what subscripting a `PFObject` returns, if it's like a dictionary, my guess is it's `AnyObject!` or `AnyObject?`, in which case it will need to be type-cast and possibly force-unwrapped with `!`. The following code will compile:

```
notifications.sorted {
    switch ($0.createdAt, $1.createdAt) {
    case (.Some(let first), .Some(let second)):
        return first.compare(second) == .OrderedAscending
    default: 
        return true
    }
}.map { $0["message"]! as String }
```

Note that in Swift 1.2, you'll need to use `as!` instead of `as` since this is an unsafe cast (from `AnyObject` to `String`). If there's a chance of `message` being nil on the object, you may also want to have some sort of fallback:

```
.map { $0["message"] as? String ?? "Default message" }
```

Comment: If you're in Swift 1.2, you might like to try `flatMap` instead of the `switch`: `notifications.sorted { lhs, rhs in rhs.createdAt.flatMap { lhs.createdAt?.compare($0) } == .OrderedAscending }`

Comment: Thanks for these answers! I have two follow up questions: 1) I also tried: `notifications.sorted { $0.createdAt!.compare($1.createdAt!) == .OrderedAscending }` (ie. force unwrapping the optional dates), and this had the same problem as in my original post. Why is that? 2) How exactly is `flatMap` helping here?